# Why can't I find the symbol tables in the C libraries in MacOS?

Tags: osx, executable, dynamic-linking

I've looked at the hexdump of both libc.dylib and xlib.dylib, and I can't find the symbols for the C functions in those libraries within those files.

I figure they should be in there, because I've done hexdumps of executable files and the symbols for variables and functions are stored in the symbol table in plain text form.

Of course, this is a linkable object file that I'm dealing with now, but I'm wondering how you can link to symbols in these libraries if the symbols aren't in the object files.

Comment: What does `nm` print?

Comment: I do not have xlib.dylib in my High Sierra...

Comment: Yeah, I think it was something else.  I was pulling the filename from memory at the time and didn't have time to check it.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in MacOS High Sierra:

```
$ ls -la libc.dylib 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  15 25 Nov 01:32 libc.dylib -> libSystem.dylib
```

`libc.dylib` is a symbolic link to `libSystem.dylib`.

When trying to display the contents of `libSystem.dylib`, you won't see many chars as depending on you using `strings` or `cat`, you will find unprintable characters, or end-of-file characters prematurely.

For understanding this, see the output of `strings`:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib 
executable_path=
@(#)PROGRAM:System.B  PROJECT:Libsystem-1252.50.4
```

`libSystem.dylib` is however a cache of several libraries chained together.

Choosing `libc.dylib` in High Sierra:

```
$ otool -L /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib
libSystem.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
    /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 80.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 60118.50.1)
    /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 62.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 562.50.17)
    /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 913.50.12)
    /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 551.3.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 28.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1205.50.76)
    /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 906.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 86.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 45.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 356.50.1)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 67.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1244.50.9)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 963.50.8)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 51.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 878.50.17)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 3147.50.1)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 140.50.6)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 172.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 765.50.51)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4570.51.2)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 161.50.1)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 301.50.1)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 829.50.17)
    /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 35.3.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1205.50.76)
```

Also as correctly @ajeh also suggests:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib  
0000000000001a6a T R8289209$_close
0000000000001a6f T R8289209$_fork
0000000000001a74 T R8289209$_fsync
0000000000001a79 T R8289209$_getattrlist
0000000000001a7e T R8289209$_getrlimit
0000000000001a83 T R8289209$_getxattr
0000000000001a88 T R8289209$_open
0000000000001a8d T R8289209$_pthread_attr_destroy
0000000000001a92 T R8289209$_pthread_attr_init
0000000000001a97 T R8289209$_pthread_attr_setdetachstate
0000000000001a9c T R8289209$_pthread_create
0000000000001aa1 T R8289209$_pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000001aa6 T R8289209$_pthread_mutex_unlock
0000000000001aab T R8289209$_pthread_self
0000000000001ab0 T R8289209$_ptrace
0000000000001ab5 T R8289209$_read
0000000000001aba T R8289209$_setattrlist
0000000000001abf T R8289209$_setrlimit
0000000000001ac4 T R8289209$_sigaction
0000000000001ac9 T R8289209$_stat
0000000000001ace T R8289209$_sysctl
0000000000001ad3 T R8289209$_time
0000000000001ad8 T R8289209$_unlink
0000000000001add T R8289209$_write
0000000000001f98 S ___System_BVersionNumber
0000000000001f60 S ___System_BVersionString
00000000000022d0 S ___crashreporter_info__
                 U ___error
                 U ___keymgr_initializer
                 U ___libdarwin_init
                 U ___libkernel_init
                 U ___libplatform_init
                 U ___malloc_init
                 U ___pthread_init
                 U ___stack_logging_early_finished
                 U __asl_fork_child
                 U __dirhelper
                 U __dyld_fork_child
                 U __dyld_initializer
                 U __libSC_info_fork_child
                 U __libSC_info_fork_parent
                 U __libSC_info_fork_prepare
                 U __libc_fork_child
                 U __libc_initializer
                 U __libcoreservices_fork_child
                 U __libsecinit_initializer
                 U __libtrace_fork_child
                 U __libtrace_init
                 U __libxpc_initializer
                 U __mach_fork_child
                 U __malloc_fork_child
                 U __malloc_fork_parent
                 U __malloc_fork_prepare
                 U __notify_fork_child
                 U __pthread_atfork_child
                 U __pthread_atfork_child_handlers
                 U __pthread_atfork_parent
                 U __pthread_atfork_parent_handlers
                 U __pthread_atfork_prepare
                 U __pthread_atfork_prepare_handlers
                 U __pthread_clear_qos_tsd
                 U __pthread_exit_if_canceled
                 U _close
                 U _dispatch_atfork_child
                 U _dispatch_atfork_parent
                 U _dispatch_atfork_prepare
                 U _dlsym
                 U _dyld_get_program_sdk_version
                 U _exit
                 U _fork
                 U _free
                 U _fsync
                 U _getattrlist
                 U _getrlimit
                 U _getxattr
0000000000001ae2 T _libSystem_atfork_child
0000000000001a47 T _libSystem_atfork_parent
0000000000001a22 T _libSystem_atfork_prepare
000000000000194a t _libSystem_initializer
00000000000022a0 s _libSystem_initializer.libc_funcs
0000000000002220 s _libSystem_initializer.libkernel_funcs
0000000000002280 s _libSystem_initializer.libpthread_funcs
                 U _libdispatch_init
0000000000001b28 t _mach_init_old
00000000000022c8 D _mach_init_routine
                 U _malloc
                 U _open
                 U _pthread_attr_destroy
                 U _pthread_attr_init
                 U _pthread_attr_setdetachstate
                 U _pthread_create
                 U _pthread_mutex_lock
                 U _pthread_mutex_unlock
                 U _pthread_self
                 U _ptrace
                 U _read
                 U _realloc
                 U _setattrlist
                 U _setrlimit
                 U _sigaction
                 U _stat
                 U _strncmp
                 U _sysctl
                 U _time
                 U _unlink
                 U _write
                 U _xpc_atfork_child
                 U _xpc_atfork_parent
                 U _xpc_atfork_prepare
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

However, a pure `nm` in `libSystem.dylib` will show the *symbols* of all the included libraries lumped together.

It might be slightly more interesting to do it to one by one as in this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `otool -L /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib | sed "1d" | awk ' { print $1 } '` 
do 
    echo $i
    echo "======="
    nm $i 
    echo
done
```

Or as one liner:

```
for i in `otool -L /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib | sed "1d" | awk ' { print $1 } '`; do echo $i; echo "=======" ; nm $i ; echo ; done
```

As for the hex dump, as you haven't show it to us, I will assume you are being confused by the 16-bit output (I think).

For seeing a few string dumps, try:

```
$ od -tc /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib  | tr -d " "  | grep -v "\\\\" | sed 's/^[0-9]*//g' | less
*
*
/usr/lib/libSyst
/system/libcache
/usr/lib/system/
libcommonCrypto.
/usr/lib/system/
libcompiler_rt.d
/usr/lib/system/
libcopyfile.dyli
/usr/lib/system/
libcorecrypto.dy
/usr/lib/system/
libdispatch.dyli
/usr/lib/system/
/system/libkeymg
/usr/lib/system/
/system/libmacho
/usr/lib/system/
libquarantine.dy
/usr/lib/system/
libremovefile.dy
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_asl.dy
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_blocks
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_c.dyli
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_config
/system/libsyste
m_coreservices.d
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_darwin
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_dnssd.
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_info.d
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_m.dyli
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_malloc
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_networ
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_networ
kextension.dylib
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_notify
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_sandbo
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_secini
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_kernel
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_platfo
/system/libsyste
/system/libsyste
m_symptoms.dylib
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_trace.
/usr/lib/system/
/system/libxpc.d
*
AVSPM211306I211317H211323H215=
@(#)PROGRAM:Syst
em.BPROJECT:Li
bsystem-1252.50.
*
*
A__pthread_cl
@__pthre
ad_exit_if_cance
@_reallo
@___keymgr_ini
__libdarwin_init
__libplatform_in
qH0@___stack_log
ging_early_finis
@__dyld_fork_chi
@__libSC_info_f
__libSC_info_for
_libSC_info_fork
__libc_fork_chil
@__libcoreserv
@__libtrace_i
__malloc_fork_ch
@__notify_for
_pthread_atfork_
thread_atfork_ch
@__pthread_at
@__pthread_atf
ork_parent_handl
read_atfork_prep
read_atfork_prep
@_dispatch_atfo
_dispatch_atfork
dispatch_atfork_
dyld_get_program
read_attr_destro
@_pthread_attr
thread_mutex_loc
q2000040@_xpc_atfork
pc_atfork_parent
setdetachstate
%025226003006006006006006006006006006

*
%#005005005005005005005005005005
$_pthread
$_pthread_
$_pthread_attr
R8289209$_pthrea
$_pthread_mutex
pthread_mutex_un
$_setattrlis
tem_BVersionNumb
rashreporter_inf
System_atfork_pa
mach_init_routin
ymgr_initializer
_logging_early_f
C_info_fork_chil
SC_info_fork_pre
oreservices_fork
__libtrace_fork_
alloc_fork_child
__pthread_atfork
_atfork_child_ha
_pthread_atfork_
__pthread_atfork
ad_atfork_prepar
read_clear_qos_t
patch_atfork_par
ogram_sdk_versio
hread_attr_destr
ttr_setdetachsta
ystem_initialize
ializer.libkerne
em_initializer.l
_libSystem_initi
alizer.libc_func
u264241247254B346e215364211362i2452q
*
ox343_z;f337cW245ک**jh037
s214220>34703030222027#365*2'
r030y311001352e=213/
I266'|D217362217257I251232330345024)
c244274301N365001006270224:037.202300030
CertificationAu
thority10260024006003U004003
pleCertificatio
nAuthority1301006
SigningCertifi
cationAuthority
kY275Z0332112633473453563169230#59
P266035006304[361]032233Te206s
/b3458275001020drm|iGa234020
&343353205302,$334j302?210374̬**
LSx373337030v2412172442512ʑ**247266
P021210253j355353f040
K254;-357252347326Ɉ**-i¤***
a/ۇ**002363241!271L237016370371331-
r004177035256n372?210263̣**@356027
Q226274317344-255302351YN]034e
'003252g243223$207Ǉ**y002271]230
ȧ**227201320036#3348231_a376
U0350170010013770040040030020012060023006003
U0350230010013770040050003001
U035016004026004024216i246
wBN004245VB234Q037206332322217
)240'206%http://www.
apple.com/applec
R025j267025030ީ***ѝ**v233036
ZHG3339l200312s336b033267:ʣ**
Z036343207332%J223233357s020223s]364
O377002323016374365363364r0322261047
'016ި**ә**217j346231373a311O362027
yA303356256310kg|314lI206L002323
yڟ**245;037Qb;"361~S
鲷****[R247306325X211r267330̳**
P227?035332j2568277{y1276
c271367205205027351m212304342030224/327o
eCertification
Authority10260024006003U
AppleCertificat
ionAuthority10260
^y204-3536242WLU354213031
M316024i321311031r365]016
#025K025Y035263224367366234236317P272301
C317017235=363+I(032310376
ε**271016331^034326313=265:255364017016
q222GSU301257/A263370373343p315243
A20732122012610X354Z0042214h263
es377g^e274I330v2373024
v0016006003U035017001001377004004003
U0350230010013770040050
U035016004026004024+
.apple.com/apple
Relianceo
nthiscertifica
tebyanyparty
assumesacceptan
ceofthethena
pplicablestanda
rdtermsandcon
ditionsofuse,
certificatepoli
cyandcertifica
tionpracticest
L-x267팛****334363w233362v322w0
O301037205203205033231=G7362251233@216
,Ա**220022330276364s233356322d017313y
o$342353ѷ**p337017E341'312361m
x355347265027027250334~"5312%325331017
k324242$#021367241254217s201`306033
ں**s031O2653316177301207U٧**231271
B373330325q236~241R267033275223B$
*307017035266M234^c310K200027P252
ationAuthority1
CodeSigningCer
tificationAutho
pleInc.10270025006003U004
wareSigning0202001"
`"]323䄢****@A
d306`=221a332R250E'236,d344
**300)270/220o244273e217200j327=h
j'275273210236<?262R9227343267310124
TR230212/#Ve345351*331Q264#372
Glu261261214321023343z301354bAt246
Ztd9?Yn317,300`203
>J373.350?023325240
i246304wBN004245VB234
www.apple.com/ce
rtificateauthori
thiscertificat
ebyanypartya
ssumesacceptanc
eofthethenap
plicablestandar
dtermsandcond
itionsofuse,c
ertificatepolic
yandcertificat
ionpracticesta
tements.05006003U035037004
.0,0*240(240&206$http:
//crl.apple.com/
codesigning.crl0
QN360212I260h224eQ"337375@2175
h@R273%216314372316|022V330300125
U005265J261265a374225|221^r321(264
+m332Kg237005374346347YJC^037
{2047276376272212+3005224P203270376232
b362031mw223343u3176Y1
VKD.230٦**1241360034
f224231Ts023265Q8274$2422400;z
e207254300274025364^0ǝ**243*004337317
G204m237375377Eà**031254<273255217
q6021355350001272264uH202
*S032005005233235306G033365350r240
U004006023002US10230021006003U
ertificationAut
*AppleCodeSign
ingCertificatio
"004f335KoV261HP276246#370i
x[346c207347ϒ**P;301b!/026」
version="1.0"en
coding="UTF-8"?>
PUBLIC"-//Appl
e//DTDPLIST1.0
//EN""http://ww
w.apple.com/DTDs
/PropertyList-1.
Lb1axSFC+piP4aX
_033X243321OU246_231:L3401351A
˥**"235^177031373321A017v^)
m376371`302016`%n201l316031336&
ж**250
c355002225375274273314304ylk314r
d211Jy231V`a245!W,kO227W
(2467213F@Ƒ**352026WH305374301F
Υ**GQ2411Pb217%333|3000312760
d3762127ٕ**214214022u326,`1.
*
/lib/libSystem.B
/usr/lib/system/
/system/libcommo
/system/libcompi
/system/libcopyf
tem/libcorecrypt
/usr/lib/system/
libdispatch.dyli
/lib/system/libd
tem/libkeymgr.dy
/lib/system/libl
tem/libmacho.dyl
/lib/system/libq
/system/libremov
tem/libsystem_as
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_blocks
/usr/lib/system/
libsystem_c.dyli
/lib/system/libs
ystem_configurat
tem/libsystem_co
reservices.dylib
/lib/system/libs
ystem_darwin.dyl
/lib/system/libs
ystem_dnssd.dyli
/lib/system/libs
ystem_info.dylib
/lib/system/libs
/system/libsyste
/system/libsyste
/system/libsyste
m_networkextensi
tem/libsystem_no
tem/libsystem_sa
tem/libsystem_se
tem/libsystem_ke
tem/libsystem_pl
/system/libsyste
/system/libsyste
m_symptoms.dylib
/lib/system/libs
ystem_trace.dyli
/lib/system/libu
tem/libxpc.dylib
*
RAM:System.BPR
OJECT:Libsystem-
*
*
hread_clear_qos_
@__pthread_exit_
@_ex
@_mall
@dyld_stub
@___libdarwin_
@___libplatfor
@___pthread_ini
_logging_early_f
q80@__libSC_info
<0@__libSC_info_
@0@__libc_fork_c
qH0@__libcoreser
vices_fork_child
@__libtrace_ini
__malloc_fork_pr
t0@__pthread_atf
ork_child_handle
ad_atfork_parent
_atfork_parent_h
_pthread_atfork_
_pthread_atfork_
prepare_handlers
@_dispatch_at
@_dispatch_atf
@_dyld_get_pro
gram_sdk_version
_pthread_attr_de
attr_setdetachst
@_pthread_mutex
hread_mutex_unlo
@_xpc_atfork_pa
ach_init_routine
shreporter_info_

$_pthread
$_pthread_
$_pthread_attr
R8289209$_pthrea
$_pthread_mutex
pthread_mutex_un
$_setattrlis
tem_BVersionNumb
rashreporter_inf
System_atfork_pa
mach_init_routin
ymgr_initializer
_logging_early_f
C_info_fork_chil
SC_info_fork_pre
oreservices_fork
__libtrace_fork_
alloc_fork_child
__pthread_atfork
_atfork_child_ha
_pthread_atfork_
__pthread_atfork
ad_atfork_prepar
read_clear_qos_t
patch_atfork_par
ogram_sdk_versio
hread_attr_destr
ttr_setdetachsta
ystem_initialize
ializer.libkerne
em_initializer.l
_libSystem_initi
alizer.libc_func
u264241247254B346e215364211362i2452q
*
:211$241R214226D257270vMgd
`340203d352237lMo327355003+374311
ɚ**2162521232001.361Dhlgi326277
a375=(033373D|323z2206{ι**
t017251341첕****337234[O2227365{177
i#{}o@H240032353g245375Yۖ
CertificationAu
thority10260024006003U004003
pleCertificatio
nAuthority1301006
SigningCertifi
cationAuthority
kY275Z0332112633473453563169230#59
P266035006304[361]032233Te206s
/b3458275001020drm|iGa234020
&343353205302,$334j302?210374̬**
LSx373337030v2412172442512ʑ**247266
P021210253j355353f040
K254;-357252347326Ɉ**-i¤***
a/ۇ**002363241!271L237016370371331-
r004177035256n372?210263̣**@356027
Q226274317344-255302351YN]034e
'003252g243223$207Ǉ**y002271]230
ȧ**227201320036#3348231_a376
U0350170010013770040040030020012060023006003
U0350230010013770040050003001
U035016004026004024216i246
wBN004245VB234Q037206332322217
)240'206%http://www.
apple.com/applec
R025j267025030ީ***ѝ**v233036
ZHG3339l200312s336b033267:ʣ**
Z036343207332%J223233357s020223s]364
O377002323016374365363364r0322261047
'016ި**ә**217j346231373a311O362027
yA303356256310kg|314lI206L002323
yڟ**245;037Qb;"361~S
鲷****[R247306325X211r267330̳**
P227?035332j2568277{y1276
c271367205205027351m212304342030224/327o
eCertification
Authority10260024006003U
AppleCertificat
ionAuthority10260
^y204-3536242WLU354213031
M316024i321311031r365]016
#025K025Y035263224367366234236317P272301
C317017235=363+I(032310376
ε**271016331^034326313=265:255364017016
q222GSU301257/A263370373343p315243
A20732122012610X354Z0042214h263
es377g^e274I330v2373024
v0016006003U035017001001377004004003
U0350230010013770040050
U035016004026004024+
.apple.com/apple
Relianceo
nthiscertifica
tebyanyparty
assumesacceptan
ceofthethena
pplicablestanda
rdtermsandcon
ditionsofuse,
certificatepoli
cyandcertifica
tionpracticest
L-x267팛****334363w233362v322w0
O301037205203205033231=G7362251233@216
,Ա**220022330276364s233356322d017313y
o$342353ѷ**p337017E341'312361m
x355347265027027250334~"5312%325331017
k324242$#021367241254217s201`306033
ں**s031O2653316177301207U٧**231271
B373330325q236~241R267033275223B$
*307017035266M234^c310K200027P252
ationAuthority1
CodeSigningCer
tificationAutho
pleInc.10270025006003U004
wareSigning0202001"
`"]323䄢****@A
d306`=221a332R250E'236,d344
**300)270/220o244273e217200j327=h
j'275273210236<?262R9227343267310124
TR230212/#Ve345351*331Q264#372
Glu261261214321023343z301354bAt246
Ztd9?Yn317,300`203
>J373.350?023325240
i246304wBN004245VB234
www.apple.com/ce
rtificateauthori
thiscertificat
ebyanypartya
ssumesacceptanc
eofthethenap
plicablestandar
dtermsandcond
itionsofuse,c
ertificatepolic
yandcertificat
ionpracticesta
tements.05006003U035037004
.0,0*240(240&206$http:
//crl.apple.com/
codesigning.crl0
QN360212I260h224eQ"337375@2175
h@R273%216314372316|022V330300125
U005265J261265a374225|221^r321(264
+m332Kg237005374346347YJC^037
{2047276376272212+3005224P203270376232
b362031mw223343u3176Y1
VKD.230٦**1241360034
f224231Ts023265Q8274$2422400;z
e207254300274025364^0ǝ**243*004337317
G204m237375377Eà**031254<273255217
q6021355350001272264uH202
*S032005005233235306G033365350r240
U004006023002US10230021006003U
ertificationAut
*AppleCodeSign
ingCertificatio
"004W021B277]240020211Q365t230213
e250267300~255)3530043172722636234272
version="1.0"en
coding="UTF-8"?>
PUBLIC"-//Appl
e//DTDPLIST1.0
//EN""http://ww
w.apple.com/DTDs
/PropertyList-1.
FCv12gEIlR9XSYi7
%022361354$:2576340025koX272
_206B353253034263ŗ**221y264255026s
**222260214220g343366240T243ֳ**252AC
CkSI{&375026321370026377
RЕ**001211204360x231g272252317344325%
P335*(023i216na202370
*
```